# Open app from facebook using universal link

Tags: ios, facebook, ios-universal-links

I have a url, posted in my feed. I want to click it on open my app. The problem is, Facebook opens its own browser, and then pops a popup asking me if I want to "Open App". Clicking on it leads to the AppStore (empty page) and not to the app.

Clicking on the link from the notes/mail app open my app directly.

The Association File is set correctly on the server.

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: It was answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396021/facebook-messenger-opens-built-in-browser-instead-of-deep-linked-app